# why this error is occuring javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0

Tags: java, exception, sslexception

What is the reason for this error? Why does it occur? I searched but found nothing

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
```

Comment: This error is quite broad. This could be result of wrong SSL handshake, when sides use different encryption protocol. Which java version you use on both sides?  What are you trying to do when your get this ?

Comment: Iam Using yubikey OTP for two factor authentication.An api request is made for the yubiko validation server to verify the yubikey OTP,Iam using the jre version 1.8.0_131 and getting this error when making a HTTPS request to the yubiko validation server

Comment: Which Java version are you using?
If the server is using http / 2, older Java doesn't support it and returns that error.